# check if xmlReader is concrete end element

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I've got xmlReader set up and can check for certain elements, but I cant find a way to check for a closing element, lets say I want to have another case statement for `</perls>` tag in addition to its opening one, how could I do this? I know for sure that such tag is not self closing.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("perls.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    // Only detect start elements.
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
        // Get element name and switch on it.
        switch (reader.Name)
        {
        case "perls":
            // Detect this element.
            Console.WriteLine("Start <perls> element.");
            break;
        case "article":
            // Detect this article element.
            Console.WriteLine("Start <article> element.");
            // Search for the attribute name on this current node.
            string attribute = reader["name"];
            if (attribute != null)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("  Has attribute name: " + attribute);
            }
            // Next read will contain text.
            if (reader.Read())
            {
            Console.WriteLine("  Text node: " + reader.Value.Trim());
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about simply check if `NodeType` equals `XmlNodeType.EndElement`, like :

```
if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
{
    ....
}
```

For reference : http://www.codingeverything.com/2013/05/extending-xmlreader-class-isendelement.html